# Using tensorflow-gpu in Arch Linux. Installing cudnn6 with cuda 8

Tags: tensorflow, archlinux, cudnn

Apparently tensorflow needs cudnn6 to use the gpu. I have cuda 8 and cudnn5 and 7 but not 6. I get this error whenever I try to import tensorflow after installing tensorflow-gpu:

```
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have cuda-8.0.61-2 installed from the repositories.

So I got cudnn6 from here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cudnn6/

And tried make -si but I get:

```
==> Making package: cudnn6 6.0.21-2 (Mon Nov 27 10:06:19 CET 2017)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Installing missing dependencies...
error: target not found: cuda-8.0
==> ERROR: 'pacman' failed to install missing dependencies.
```

Any idea how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

*. Uninstall cuda from repository, install https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cuda-8.0/

or

*. Delete dependensi to cuda 8 from cudnn 6 pkg file, "depends=('cuda-8.0')"

I prefer solution 1 becouse it not will break the package dependency

Comment: Thank you. I found a better solution for cudnn 6. On the comments of the AUR package page it says that the PKGBUILD is broken and there's a link for a new one that works correctly